# How type inference works in java when it comes to generics?

Tags: java, generics

```
public class gen1<T>{
    T var1;

    public gen1(T arg1)
    {
        var1=arg1;
    }
    void meth1(T arg1){

    }

    void meth2(gen1<? extends RuntimeException> arg)
    {

    }
}

public class gen2 extends gen1{
    public gen2(){
        super(new Exception());
        meth2(new gen1(Integer.valueOf(12))); //This should throw an error but it doesn't 
    }
}
```

The above is a gen1 Generic class.
Below is gen2 class which extends gen1

Tell me why is the line  **"meth2(new gen1(Integer.valueOf(12)));"**  not throwing an error.
I am violating the upper bound i.e the type parameter should extend RuntimeException but here I am passing an Integer object

Comment: Because you are using the raw type. Look at the warnings the compiler emitted...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The above is a gen1 Generic class. Below is gen2 class which extends gen1

You've buried the lede here. In java, you don't just inherit the type variables of your parent class. If you want `gen2` to also inherit the idea 'this class is parameterized; it has one type variable', you need to declare it as such:

```
public class gen2<T> extends gen1<T> {}
```

What you've done in your snippet is `extends gen1` which means you've removed the generics: You're now in legacy/raw mode, and **all generics and all benefits of it, for all uses of that entire class everywhere** are gone. Legacy/Raw should not be used and you're using it here. How does type inference work in such a case? It doesn't, is the simple answer.

You lose the type inference even in places where the fact that you use raw/legacy would appear not to actually negatively impact the ability of the compiler to type infer. That's not how it works: You are in raw mode, so **all** generics-based inference is turned off, whether that was actually needed to make raw/legacy work or not.

**`javac` would have warned you that you opted out of inferring or type-checking any and all generics in relation to any and all use of `gen2` in your code, and you ignored that warning. Stop ignoring that warning.**

Because you ignored it, all `T` in all of gen2's signatures, including the ones inherited from gen1, turn into its upper bound which is Object, so, `meth2(someInstanceOfGen1)` is fine, as the `meth2` method requires as parameter one `Object`, and that's what you're passing.

`new gen1(Integer.valueOf(12))` works fine too - `new gen1` means you're in raw mode (you wanted `new gen1<RuntimeException>(Integer.valueOf(12))` - that would have generated a compile time error - if you want type inference, you wanted `new gen1<>(Integer.valueOf(12))`, which would have inferred that you meant to write `new gen1<Integer>` - and whether that's okay or not depends on what you do with it. Here you pass it to `meth2`, which is fine, as `meth2` is raw/legacy mode due to `class gen1 extends gen2`.

### So what should you have done?

```
public class Gen1<T> {
    T var1;

    public gen1(T arg1)
    {
        var1=arg1;
    }
    void meth1(T arg1){

    }

    void meth2(gen1<? extends RuntimeException> arg)
    {

    }
}

public class gen2<T> extends gen1<T> {
    public gen2(){
        super(new Exception());
        meth2(new gen1<>(Integer.valueOf(12))); // compile time error here
    }
}
```

And you say 'this should throw an error' which is just not how it works either, you misunderstand this stuff rather thoroughly.

**Generics are ENTIRELY a figment of the compiler's imagination**.

At runtime, generics **do not exist in any way**. `java.exe` has no idea what they are. In the conversion from a `.java` file to a `.class` file, most of the generics are gone entirely (javac uses them to generate warnings, errors, and inject silent casts, then mostly eliminates them), and the few that remain in the class file are treated as a comment by the runtime - it just skips past them and has no idea what they mean nor do they effect what the runtime does in any way. They exist in class files solely so that `javac` knows what to do when you stick that class file on the classpath when compiling some code, that is all.

and 'throw' is entirely a runtime thing. A compiler does not 'throw' anything. It produces compiler errors or warnings. Hence why generics violations must not be described as causing the 'throwing' of things. They live in different universes; one is a compiler concern only, one is a runtime concern only.

At best a convoluted and buggy mess that dips into generics warnings (where the compiler explicitly tells you: Due to using raw types and/or casting to generics which cannot be properly done as casting is a runtime thing and generics are a compile time thing, I cannot actually guarantee that type safety is ensured) will result in `ClassCastException` being thrown at runtime on lines that contain zero casts (because the CCEx is caused by a cast that the compiler injected silently to make generics 'work').

Comment: Suggested type inference as in `public class gen2<T> extends gen1<T> { public gen2(){  super(new Exception());` is not valid...

Comment: Sure it is, Jean-Baptiste, as long as `gen1` has the right constructor. The provided code snippet in the question isn't complete and wouldn't compile due to that missing constructor. It has nothing to do with the question. I answered what's being asked, not nitpicked the issues.

Comment: gen2.java:3: error: constructor gen1 in class gen1<T#2> cannot be applied to given types;
        super(new Exception());
        ^
  required: T#1
  found:    Exception
  reason: argument mismatch; Exception cannot be converted to T#1
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in class gen2
    T#2 extends Object declared in class gen1

Comment: Write an appropriate constructor, @Jean-Baptiste. You're nitpicking something that isn't there, on a part of the question that isn't relevant. I don't know what you're doing, but it's not making this answer any better.

Answer (score 3):

When defining a generic type, the compiler emits a raw type (a "standard" class where type parameters are erased). Type parameter and constraints are just part of the game at compile-time, there is nothing such as this at runtime.

When you use `gen1` in place of `gen1<something>` you are using the raw type, not the generic one.

Let us examine the `gen1` (raw) class (`javap -c -s gen1`):

```
Compiled from "gen1.java"
public class gen1<T> {
  T var1;
    descriptor: Ljava/lang/Object;

  public gen1(T);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0
       5: aload_1
       6: putfield      #7                  // Field var1:Ljava/lang/Object;
       9: return

  void meth1(T);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    Code:
       0: return

  void meth2(gen1<? extends java.lang.RuntimeException>);
    descriptor: (Lgen1;)V
    Code:
       0: return
}
```

Important things are the descriptors. This means that if you use the raw class `gen1`, its constructor takes an `Object`, `m1` takes an `Object` and `m2` takes a `gen1`. That's all, every things related to `T` and constraints disappeared.

Now as you used the raw type there is no type inference! The compiler just warns you about all of this:

```
gen2.java:3: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to gen1(T) as a member of the raw type gen1
        super(new Exception());
             ^
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class gen1
gen2.java:4: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to gen1(T) as a member of the raw type gen1
        meth2(new gen1(Integer.valueOf(12))); //This should throw an error but it doesn't 
              ^
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class gen1
gen2.java:4: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to meth2(gen1<? extends RuntimeException>) as a member of the raw type gen1
        meth2(new gen1(Integer.valueOf(12))); //This should throw an error but it doesn't
```

It warns you but let you make everything you want; everything is on your responsibility now.
You are using raw type for no reason, it is not recommended to use raw types anymore (except in some weird cases).

Now if we try to introduce instanciations of generic we will see the error...

First:

```
public class gen2 extends gen1<Exception>{
    public gen2(){
        super(new Exception());
        meth2(new gen1(Integer.valueOf(12))); //This should throw an error but it doesn't
    }
}
```

slightly change the things. Now compiler can ensure that the call to `super(new Exception())`  is correct (the super class is `gen1<Exception>`).

Now trying to eliminate other warnings let us introduce a generic type instanciation to the call of `meth2`:

```
public class gen2 extends gen1<Exception>{
    public gen2(){
        super(new Exception());
        meth2(new gen1<Integer>(Integer.valueOf(12))); //This should throw an error but it doesn't
    }
}
```

Compiler can ensure that instanciation of `gen1` is type safe.
But the compiler now emits the error you were looking for:

```
gen2.java:4: error: method meth2 in class gen1<T> cannot be applied to given types;
        meth2(new gen1<Integer>(Integer.valueOf(12))); //This should throw an error but it doesn't 
        ^
  required: gen1<? extends RuntimeException>
  found:    gen1<Integer>
  reason: argument mismatch; gen1<Integer> cannot be converted to gen1<? extends RuntimeException>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class gen1
1 error
```

`gen1<Integer>` is not subtype of `gen1<? extends RuntimeException>`, that is false, it is an error.

By the use of the raw types, you bypass all of these checkings; do not try again.